# Invoke Lambdas asynchronously using boto3 locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda, boto3, python-asyncio

I've set a Lambda in AWS that reads an object in an s3 an does some processing. The thing is, I have many of such objects in the bucket, and I want to process all of them. Hence, I was planning on invoking the Lambda function locally using boto3:

```py
functioname = 'lambda_handler'

for p in tqdm(payloads):
    client.invoke(
        FunctionName = functioname,
        InvocationType = 'Event',
        LogType = 'None',
        ClientContext = 'string',
        Payload = p
    )
```

The problem is, the code above is NOT async, the loop only moves on to the next case after a second or so. What is going on? Is there a work around this?

Comment: Are you saying that you added timing diagnostics into this code and each iteration of the loop takes approximately one second? Or are you simply timing the entire script? Do you know what your configured concurrency limit is for this Lambda function and the underlying AWS account?

Comment: The time is from observing from `tqdm`.

Comment: I didn't know about this configs. I'll try to check it.

Comment: For a very simple Lambda function that does no more than `print(event)` (although the processing should not matter as it's an async invocation), I see approximately 10 to 12 invocations per second to a Lambda function with default concurrency options in the nearest AWS region.

Comment: I havent changed the original config for my lambda. The Lambda is reading an S3 file and  writing to a DocumentDB. Perhaps the issue is that the DocumentDB does not allow concurrence?

Comment: Perhaps you could create a very basic Lambda function and test that first, to see if the invocation rate is the same (1/sec) or better (10/sec). Also, what is your payload? In my test I send a small JSON string.

Comment: The payload is the file name in the s3 bucket.

Comment: Removed the bit for inserting into the DocumentDB, and still no concurrency.

Comment: I'm assuming the Lambda service endpoint you're making requests to is somewhat local (e.g. is not the other side of the world). I'd consider enabling debug logging for boto3 to see if it's being throttled.

Comment: thanks. Yeah. Not other side of the world

Comment: Also read [Troubleshoot invocation issues in Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/troubleshooting-invocation.html).

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question "I have many of such objects in the bucket, and I want to process all of them.", the easiest way to achieve this is to enable the S3 Event trigger on the lambda that you want to process the files referencing the bucket where the files are located.

Then go into the bucket and select the files and copy them back into the bucket.  That will trigger the S3 event for each file in its own lambda.

An added advantage is that any future files put into the bucket will also be processed going forward.

If you need to use the CLI to copy the files you can use a command like this:

```
aws s3 cp s3://<your bucket>/ s3://<your bucket> --recursive
```

Comment: I think this might be a feasible solution. But how can one then copy the same set of files to the bucket asynchronously in python?

Comment: Do it from the console.  Two clicks.

Comment: I have to many files, this would be unfeasible from within the console. :x

Comment: CLI command should work, something like "aws s3 cp s3://bucket s3://bucket".  Please test it first :)

Comment: This cli command does not work :(

Comment: It was a generic example.  I'll update the answer with something more specific.